# How to allow ScrollView in React Native to extend to the status bar area in IOS?

Tags: react-native

I'm having trouble setting my ScrollView to extend to the status bar area .

for example

```
  return (
      <View  style={{flex:1}}>
      <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
      <Text>Random Text</Text>
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
```

returns this for me , which bascially set the text right below the status bar area .

[Current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgdyc.png)

I was hopping to actually have it look like this.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSlc3.png)

How can I got about achieving this ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

Adding

```
contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="never"
```

to ScrollView does it.

```
  return (
      <View  style={{flex:1}}>
      <ScrollView
      contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="never"
      style={{flex:1}}>
      <Text>Random Text</Text>
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
```

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3821

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick in React Native 0.63.3. Without it, ScrollView would always avoid using the statusbar area at the top and the bottom area of the screen on iPhone X and 11 gen phones.

Answer (score 0):

By default it will extend to the top, make sure you are not using safe-area. Also try setting text with absolute position and top as 0.

Comment: Thanks you , but it didn't extend to the top at all . As you can from the code above , I'm not using safe-view-area at all . It seems as if ScrollView has its own safe-view-area settings

Answer (score 0):

"I am on react-native 0.59.9 and when I set `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"` on ScrollView, FlatList or SectionList, the padding is correctly added at the bottom and the content is allowed to scroll beneath the bottom part where the "home button" is.
There is no need to use a SafeAreaView to achieve this."

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16997#issuecomment-526923753